# How to calculate years to gain 5 million net worth?

Tags: finance

Givens:

- 20% annual growth
- 30k payments/year

---

FV of Annuity$=P[\frac{(1+r)^n-1}{r}]$

$P=$ Periodic payment

$r=$ Rate per period

$n=$ Number of periods

$5000 = 30\cdot((1+0.2)^n-1)/0.2$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=5000+%3D+30*%28%281%2B0.2%29%5En-1%29%2F0.2

$n = $ **19.4 years**

---

Alternatively

`=FV(20%,19.4,30000)`

## Or should this be PV?

Comment: Is there any interest rate given?

Comment: 20% annual growth

Comment: This is the interest rate?

Comment: There is no interest rate. This is the return rate. E.g., 100 invested garners 120 after a year.

Comment: Then your calculation is right. You need 20 years to earn 5 million monetary units.